How do I get user details in Python web app deployed on Azure App Service authenticated with Microsoft Identity provider?
I have built a web app using Python Dash package and deployed this app on Azure App Service. The web app is currently authenticated through the Azure Portal's app service authenticate using Microsoft Identity Provider. But how do I get the signed in user details? And how do I authenticate my web app when running locally?
My current sign-in flow is also auto redirect so there is no sign in page and no logout button/option.
I wish to get signed in user details and this is what I have implemented so far:
authentication.py
import msal
import requests

authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>'
scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
client_id = <client-id>
client_secret = <client-secret>


def authentication():
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id,
        authority=authority,
        client_credential=client_secret
    )

    token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    access_token = token_response['access_token']

    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }

    response = requests.get(
        'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', headers=headers)
    user_data = response.json()

    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    for key, value in user_data.items():
        print(f'{key}: {value}')
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

    return

And this is my app.py where I called the authentication function:
from functions.app import authentication
# other imports ...

stylesheets = [
    "https://unpkg.com/@mantine/dates@7/styles.css",
    "https://unpkg.com/@mantine/code-highlight@7/styles.css",
    "https://unpkg.com/@mantine/charts@7/styles.css",
    "https://unpkg.com/@mantine/carousel@7/styles.css",
    "https://unpkg.com/@mantine/notifications@7/styles.css",
    "https://unpkg.com/@mantine/nprogress@7/styles.css",
]

app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, external_stylesheets=stylesheets)

server = app.server

authentication.authentication()

app.layout = dmc.MantineProvider(
    ... # layout stuff
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8000)

But this is what I am getting when I run my python dash web app (python ./app.py):
{'error': {'code': 'BadRequest', 'message': '/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.', 'innerError': {'date': '2024-08-05T03:46:12', 'request-id': '<request-id>', 'client-request-id': '<client-request-id>'}}}


Your authentication process uses client credentials flow to generate access token which won't work to call /me for fetching signed-in user details.
Initially, I too got same error when I used client credentials flow to generate token and used it to call /me endpoint:

To get signed-in user details, switch to delegated flows like interactive flow or authorization code flow that involves user to login at least once.
For interactive flow, make sure to add redirect URI in Mobile and Desktop applications platform and enable public client flow option like this:

In my case, I ran below sample code that uses interactive flow for generating token and got signed-in user details successfully in response like this:
authentication.py:
import msal
import requests

authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId'
client_id = "appId"
scope = ["User.Read"]

def authentication():
    try:
        app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
            client_id,
            authority=authority
        )
        
        token_response = app.acquire_token_interactive(
            scopes=scope,
        )
        
        if 'access_token' not in token_response:
            raise Exception("Failed to acquire token: " + str(token_response))

        access_token = token_response['access_token']

        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
        }

        response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            user_data = response.json()
            print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            for key, value in user_data.items():
                print(f'{key}: {value}')
            print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        else:
            raise Exception(f"API request failed with status code {response.status_code}: {response.text}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

authentication()

Response:


Thanks for this @Sridevi. But is there a way to implement msal.ConfidentialClientApplication instead of msal.PublicClientApplication and have the same flow? And from this provided Github: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-docs-code-python/blob/main/flask-web-app/app.py from Microsoft, I was able to sign-in and get user details, but is there a way to implement this in Dash and instead of needing users to click sign-in, when user hits the URL or when running locally, when the app initially starts, it does a sign-in?

If you want to use msal.ConfidentialClientApplication instead of msal.PublicClientApplication, switch to authorization code flow which requires user to get authorization code first by signing in and then generates token. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=python#authorization-code-provider
